# How to run linux daemon in container linked to another container with docker-compose?

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, daemon

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file which runs nginx with PHP support:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: my-app-nginx
    image: nginx:1.13.6
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./my-app:/var/www/my-app
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - php
  php:
    container_name: my-app-php
    image: php:7.1-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./my-app:/var/www/my-app
    restart: always
```

The PHP application inside `/var/www/my-app` needs to communicate with a linux daemon (let's call it `myappd`).

The way I see it, I need to either:

1. Copy the `myappd` into the `nginx` container to `/usr/local/bin`, make it executable with `chmod +x` and run it in the background.
2. Create a different container, copy `myappd` to `/usr/local/bin`, make it executable with `chmod +x` and run it in the foreground.

Now, I'm new to Docker and I'm researching and learning about it but my best guess, given that I'm using Docker Composer, is that option 2 is probably the recommended one? Given my limited knowledge about Docker, I'd have to guess that this container would require some sort of linux-based image (like Ubuntu or something) to run this binary. So maybe option 1 is preferred? Or maybe option 2 is possible with a minimal Ubuntu image or maybe it's possible without such image?

Either way, I have no idea how would I implement that on the composer file. Especially option 2, how would the PHP application communicate with the daemon in a different container? Just "sharing" a volume (where the binary is located) like I did for nginx/php services would suffice? Or something else is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is adding `command` entry to `php` service in docker-compose.yml.

Given that `myappd` is at ./my-app/ on host machine and at /var/www/my-app/, updated docker-compose.yml is something like following.

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: my-app-nginx
    image: nginx:1.13.6
    ports:
       - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./my-app:/var/www/my-app
    restart: always
    depends_on:
       - php
  php:
    container_name: my-app-php
    image: php:7.1-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./my-app:/var/www/my-app
    restart: always
    command: ["/bin/sh", "/var/www/my-app/mappd", "&&", "php-fpm"]
```

---

Better answer is to create the third container which runs linux daemon.

New Dockerfile is something like following.

```
FROM debian:jessie

COPY ./myappd /usr/src/app/

EXPOSE 44444

ENTRYPOINT ['/bin/sh']
CMD ['/usr/src/app/myappd']
```

Build image and name it `myapp/myappd`.

Updated docker-compose.yml is something like following.

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: my-app-nginx
    image: nginx:1.13.6
    ports:
       - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./my-app:/var/www/my-app
    restart: always
    depends_on:
       - php
  php:
    container_name: my-app-php
    image: php:7.1-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./my-app:/var/www/my-app
    restart: always
    networks:
      - network1
    depends_on:
       - daemon
  daemon:
    container_name: my-app-daemon
    image: myapp/myappd
    restart: always
    networks:
      - network1
networks:
  network1:
```

You can send request with hostname `daemon` from inside `php`. Docker container has capability to resolve hostname of another container in the same network.

Comment: Your question is my original question. That's what I need to know how to do.

Comment: I am not saying where myappd should be put, but ask the fact where is the original myappd now. On the host machine?

Comment: Yes, it's in the host machine, I need to copy it to the container and have it running in the background.

Comment: I think option2 is the preferable. The base image of `php:7.1-fpm` is debian:jessie, so this image has capability to run `myappd` binary.

Comment: linux daemon must be run before php starts? In other words, php depends on linux daemon? I want to know the relationship between php and linux daemon.

Comment: Yes, the Daemon must run before PHP starts.

Comment: That will work but what if the daemon crashes? It won't reload. The reload option will only look at the last foreground command right?

Comment: As you say, daemon process will be restarted when crashed, in this way

Comment: If you want to manage daemon process, you should treat it as independent service. So you should create third container. But your daemon process has capability to communicate with remote host? If it does not, can it communicate with unix socket? I want to know how php communicate with daemon now.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral I'm sorry, misstyped. will NOT be restarted when crashed.

Comment: I don't know the answers to those questions, will need to investigate first.

Comment: I might not sure but I believe it communicates through jsonrpc over http and I think the deamon is listening on port port 44444. I will only be able to confirm this tomorrow. Time for bed.

Comment: If it is true, you can send http request from php container to linux daemon container. If you make the two containers in the same network, service name is alias of hostname.

Comment: But how do you configure the docker container for that?

Comment: I have few questions: 1) do I still need the command on the php container since we know have an extra container for the daemon? 2) I'm on mobile but isn't the networks configuration incomplete? 3) what image is that on the daemon container? Where is it defined?

Comment: Ignore question 3, didn't notice the top of the answer where you mention a new dockerfile. But that requires me to build that image separately, CA t that be done automatically when calling docker-compose up -d?

Comment: Better yet, can't I just have the whole thing in the docker-compose file?

Comment: 1) No, that's my mistake, 2) I'm sorry but I can't understand the question. I'm not so good at English so please write easy English... 3+) If you want to build image automatically, add `build` entry to `daemon` service and specify where the Dockerfile is. The explanation of `build` entry is at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build

Comment: I updated answer for deleting `command` entry in `php` service.

Comment: If you wanna have the whole thing in only docker-compose.yml, fix `image` entry to `debian:jessie`, add `volumes` entry to include `myappd` on container, `command` entry to run the daemon, and `expose` entry to expose port 44444 in `daemon` service. But if `myappd` needs additional package to run, you need to define new image so need Dockerfile.

Comment: I'll read the documentation on all the settings you placed above and try to understand the whole thing better. Will get back to you later. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got everything working as I wanted it. Well, sort of... The PHP can't communicate with the daemon but I suspect the problem is not the Docker configuration, but the actual communication that might be wrong (I mean, exposing port 44444 might not be enough or correct). But that is a different issue that I'll have to debug outside Docker first. Thanks again for everything.